# Composer package building

Tags: composer-php

how can I set the directory in which my package should be installed from composer? So at the moment I have only my add-on-structure but it must be copied in a special directory of contao where the modules are.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Sorry! What is the question exactly ?

Comment: How I can set the install directory of my package files in the target structure, or where to set it.

Comment: Are you looking for the file structure ?

Comment: [This may help](http://grossi.io/2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package/).

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I understand is you are looking for a way to install your package other than the vendor folder where composer installs.

It is good to not set your directory other than vendor though. But it is possible with a composer-installer package though.

You want to define the type something like `"type": "aura-package",` see https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Web/blob/cbac024947c0c9a1a72390badcc332eebe5ea314/composer.json#L3 and set an installer which can understand what do with the installation (https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Web/blob/cbac024947c0c9a1a72390badcc332eebe5ea314/composer.json#L16).

You can see installers example over https://github.com/auraphp/installer-default ( which does nothing other than to help with the system ) . You should check the code over https://github.com/auraphp/installer-system .

And in your `composer.json` you should point to `your-installer-system` which is something similar to https://github.com/auraphp/installer-system

There are other installer-systems available in composer https://github.com/composer/installers . Please see if that fits your needs.